# Apache mod_proxy_hcheck with AJP?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, ajp

I have `BalancerMember`s using AJP with the `mod_proxy_hcheck` module; however, the health check requests are HTTP. The documentation doesn't seem to specify it only works with HTTP and the source does reference AJP in a comment.

Does anyone know if `mod_proxy_hcheck` can make AJP requests for the health checks? Or does it need to be HTTP?

- RHEL 7
- Apache httpd 2.4.34 from Software Collections

**Edit**:

Just to clarify, the reverse proxy requests are made using AJP and work fine.
Running tcpdump shows the actual health check requests are being made in the background via HTTP to the host:port used by the `BalancerMember`s (but with the wrong protocol). This results in `SEVERE: Invalid message received with signature 18245` and Tomcat immediately resetting the connection.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that only HTTP is allowed. Check this bug: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62120